# Problema con recursividad

Tags: java

Actualmente estoy aprendiendo recursividad y se me dio un problema que dice lo siguiente:

> Realiza un programa que permita recorrer mediante la recursividad en busqueda de un numero 6", ofreciendo como propuesta para la solución: "El encabezado del método puede ser: `public boolean contieneUn6(int[] nums, int index)`"

Yo ya logre hacerlo mediante una alternativa con void, pero aun así, me gustaría entenderlo de esta forma propuesta, el problema es que llevo un montón de tiempo sin saber que es lo que hace el error exactamente (El error es que nunca se muestra el falso), al recorrerlo paso por paso puedo deducir que es debido a los retornos de métodos anteriores llamados, pero la verdad no tengo ni idea.

Si pudieran decirme en que falla lo que hice y una solución de como se supone que seria el correcto seria de mucha ayuda.

```
public static void main (String[] args){
        int [] numeros; 
        int cantidad; 
        int numero;
        boolean resultado; 
        
        do{
            cantidad = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la cantidad de numeros"));
        }while(cantidad <= 0 );
        
        numeros = new int [cantidad];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++){
            do{
                numero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el numero "));
            }while(numero <= 0);
            numeros[i] = numero; 
        }
        if(contiene(numeros, 0)== true){
            System.out.println("CONTIENE 6");
        }else{
            System.out.println("NO CONTIENE 6");
        }

    }

public static boolean contiene(int[] numeros, int indice){
        if(indice == numeros.length){
            return false;
        }
        if(numeros[indice] != 6 && indice < numeros.length){
            contiene(numeros, indice+1);
        }
        return true; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es lo siguiente supón que no existe ningún 6 en el arreglo, entonces como estás llamando a `contiene(numeros, indice + 1)`, llegará el momento en que llegues al final del arreglo y retorne falso, pero no lo estás capturando y aún así estás retornando true.
Lo correcto sería:

```
public static boolean contiene(int[] numeros, int indice){
        if(indice == numeros.length){
            return false;
        }
        if(numeros[indice] != 6){
           return contiene(numeros, indice+1);
        }
        return true; 
    }
```

Ya que si entras en el `if(numeros[indice] != 6 && indice < numeros.length)` tu respuesta depende de lo que de tu recursividad en el siguiente índice.
Igual en el `if` puedes quitar la condición `(indice < numeros.length)`, ya que cuando llegues al final del arreglo vas a retornar falso y no vas a continuar.

Comment: Graciaaaaaaas, me sirvió mucho.

Comment: Perfecto, de nada!!!